# 3 adjacent electric outlets not working

Tags: receptacle

In my kitchen there are 3 adjacent electric outlets that have not been working for a few months.  Next to them is a GFCI outlet and that works. I checked the circuit breaker and all GFCIs to see any of them tripped - they all seem to be fine.  I opened all non working outlets and also the GFCI working outlet to see if any of them have a loose connection or burnt wire.  I could not find any. All the non-working outlets are on the same circuit - I can see the wiring being terminated in one of the non-working outlet Anything else I can do, before I can call the electrician?

Comment: Are the outlets using the back stabs or push in connectors these are a big failure point, other than that is possibly a broken wire at a wire nut, or a wire that has pulled out from a wire nut but this is rare but possible. Check the first non working outlet or the the last one that works on that circuit.

Comment: All of the outlets are side screw type, not the push-ins.  Wire nuts seems to be tight - I wiggled them a bit. Perhaps I am not looking at the right working outlet on that circuit - i just examined the adjacent working outlet (which is GFCI). Is there a way to map the circuit to see what is the adjacent outlet to the non-working ones?

Comment: Before you call an electrician, Are you sure the outlets that don't work are on the same circuit? Kitchens have a lot of circuits and the NEC requires at least 2 small appliance circuit for above the counter tops. Check around the kitchen there should be at least 2 GFCI receptacles or 2 GFCI breakers in the panel for the kitchen. My second question is do you have a multimeter so you can take some voltage and continuity readings? If you don't have a meter and don't feel comfortable using one, then it might be time to call your electrician.